# init instance variable multiple times

Tags: objective-c

can this code cause any potential trouble?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *instanceDictionary;

for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
   self.instanceDictionary = [NSDictionary alloc] init];
}
```

or without self

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
   instanceDictionary = [NSDictionary alloc] init];
}
```

I came across situations where a instance variable gets "overridden" like this and was wondering if it could cause any memory problems.

Comment: you re assigning a new reference to the same variable each time, and that reference gets overwritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't cause any "memory problem". In your code, at each loop iteration, the `instanceDictionary` is replaced with a new one.
`ARC` will take care of releasing the previous one automatically.
This code is pretty useless though.

Comment: It should be noted that in the first example, the memory wouldn't be a problem under MRC but the 2nd approach would be a huge leak under MRC. Both are fine (but pointless) under ARC.

Comment: I don´t understand why would the second example be a huge leak under MRC?

Comment: Because you assign memory and immediately forget the pointer to it, so you won't be able to release it manually.